# Range of reasonable sample size (for real world calculation) in Applied Statistics

Tags: sample-size

What is the range of sample sizes that can be called "reasonable"  or "reasonable for real world calculation" as per graduate level statistics/applied statistics courses in US?

I have seen questions like this a lot in my online tutoring career and I thought there might be some rule of thumb because they never give any budget related idea. But I could not find any rule in any statistics book. Following is just one such question that I solved 2 years ago, and I myself explained the student that this is a subjective question (part b). But since the student pay me for correctly answering their questions, I wish to know if there is a rule of thumb to solve their question (only asking for part b i.e, is this size reasonable).

[image: Statistics question]

Please note that I personally *know* that part (b) is subjective. Obviously this will depend on huge number of factors. Reasonable size for you might not be a reasonable size for me as our budgets might be different. I just wish to know the answer from a student's perspective who is giving the quiz. What can I tell the student so that they get their quiz correct. I have no idea what their professor taught, and I cannot ask that to them.

Comment: You have a right to be puzzled. Without context the question is comparable with is this piece of string long enough? At best there are rules of thumb, such as sample sizes being at least 30 for some purposes, but a large part of the art is knowing that, and knowing how,  rules of thumb are not exact or binding on all cases.

Comment: @NickCox I have added a sample context.

Comment: Thank you for adding that.  Unfortunately, it only demonstrates that this is a lousy quiz question: it does not make it on topic here, for the reasons you have given.  "Reasonable" is in the eye of the beholder as well as dependent on an unstated context.  Your concern really is about the psychology of people who formulate online quiz questions--you might need to provide your students some insight into that if they want not to be too frustrated--but it's not about statistics.

Comment: @whuber I agree with you. I do provide them some insight. I was hoping to find someone who had done a course like this, maybe they would know the "rule of thumb" taught by this instructor. Also, I don't mind getting no answer on this. I just wanted to try asking this once here. Now I know I have tried my best to find the answer of such questions.

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly a question very much dependent on context. Factors that enter it are practicalities such as budget, available subjects, time to completion, importance of the question, impact/cost of a wrong answer (may differ dramatically between false positives and false negatives) etc. E.g. in early clinical trials low double digit numbers of patients are quite typical, but later on a promising drug may be tested on hundreds, thousands (e.g. cardiovascular long-term outcomes studies often involve several thousands of patients, there are a good number of such studies with >10,000 patients treated for several years) or very rarely even more patients (e.g. the Salk polio vaccine trial).

Other industries may have totally different typical numbers, e.g. Google or Amazon presumably can easily test changes to their user interface very easily on a large number of randomly chosen consumers (but I don't know what numbers they usually use).

If you are asked to judge this as a multiple choice question, then I would assume that your professor or the course has provided an idea of typical numbers in the specific context being discussed, because it is otherwise very hard to judge. Another way to think about it is to guesstimate what your budget would have to be to do the experiment: if it's a couple of dollars, then it is clearly not a very demanding sample size, if we are talking hundreds of millions of dollars then it is a rather challenging experiment to finance.

Comment: I agree with every point you said, but being an online tutor, I have to tell them the answer (with explanation off-course), but I get paid for providing them answer. These questions never give any idea of budget, so I thought there must be some rule of thumb. I myself have not been able to find what rule their professor teach, so I asked here if anyone knows any rule of thumb for questions like these.

Comment: @User49582934: If you read the example questions carefully, you'll see there is at least a little context, & students are expected to use background knowledge to answer.

Comment: ...yet in other disciplines samples can be small, e.g. in experimental psychology they are often quite small (few dozen up to few hundred participants), to give other example, in biological research laboratory experiments are often conducted on just a few animals etc.

Comment: What's the answer to my example question as it is then?

Comment: You keep editing the question, but for the latest one (125 statistics students to get an estimate of their mean IQ), I mostly feel that the whole question and the answer options are bizarre. Personally, I would feel that to ask 125 people to fill in a questionnaire for, say, 1 h of their life, is quite an effort to answer a scientific question I do not think is very interesting... But if you care a lot, it is of course doable for a budget of a few hundred to a few thousand dollars.

Comment: @Björn I keep editing it but my main question is same, if there is a rule of thumb to tell whether or not a size is "Reasonable" then I want to know it. Also, Chegg is anonymous platform, and I cannot ask student what the name of course is. I mean I can ask, but student's reply is returned to next tutor, not me. I have been facing these quesitons for over 2 years now and I just wanted to try asking here once.

Comment: Also, yes, it is a silly question. But I have to face it many times. And I myself could not solve it with confidence. That's why I am asking for help here.

Comment: Realistically, I cannot see how there could be a clear answer here.

Comment: @Björn I only asked this question on this forum because I thought someone knew the "rule of thumb for reasonable sample sizes". I did not know if it existed. I cannot stress this enough, I am not looking for a real answer. I am just hoping to find something that this professor expects from their students. Something that points to one of the options. Otherwise I myself have been giving "this is subjective" answer to this question for past 2 years. And then I get bad review from the student for incorrect/incomplete solution.

Comment: And it is okay, I can peacefully give up now since I know nobody knows the "answer" that this professor is looking for :)